# Java - Ssl stream is cancelled when using client certificate authentication

Tags: java, ssl, nginx, client-certificates

I cannot figure this one out.

I have a unit test that performs a connection to my service using a client certificate authentication.

```
// generate a valid client cert and store it in a keystore
String keystorePassword = "xxx";
InputStream pkcs12 = UnitTests.generatePkcs12ForUser(user, keystorePassword, 3600);
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
ks.load(pkcs12, keystorePassword.toCharArray());


String url = getBaseServerUrl();

// prepare a ssl context that has the keystore with client cert and key
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
                                   .loadKeyMaterial(ks, keystorePassword.toCharArray())
                                   // trust all SSL certs
                                   .loadTrustMaterial((X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) -> true)
                                   .build();

// validate any hostname, and don't follow 3XX responses
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                                   .setSSLContext(sslContext)
                                   .setSSLHostnameVerifier((a,b) -> true)
                                   .disableRedirectHandling()
                                   .build();

// this fails catastrophically
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
```

I'm using Java 8 and my server is behind a reverse proxy that uses Nginx.

My unit test fails with an exception like this:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1002)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
[...]
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
    ... 43 more
```

And I can see in the Nginx error.log the following line:

```
2018/05/18 15:34:12 [crit] 42#42: *327 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error) while SSL handshaking, client: 172.18.0.1, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

I have SCOURGED the internet to find the reason for this error, and I feel like I have exhausted all recourse.

Non exhaustive list of things I have tried:

- Force java to use TlsV1.1 with `-Dhttps.protocols=Tlsv1.1` -> still fails
- Tried to specify the "key strategy" for the `loadTrustMaterial` to always use my own key -> still fails
- Used a Jersey client with the same set of Ssl /Keystore params -> still fails
- Tried all JDK versions of 1.8: OpenJDK, Oracle, and Oracle with Crypto Extensions (JCE)
- Searching the nginx error seems to imply that the passed cert wasn't correct, so I...
- ...dumped the key and cert into a couple of PEM files while in debugger and `curl`ed the same address -> it works ?!
- Wiresharked the connection and examined the TLS negotiation. Compared it with a working sample (the simple `curl -k <url>` above which works flawlessly):

  - Saw something about [ALPN](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7301) but enabling it in Java doesn't fix the exception.
  - Saw different crypto algorithms announced but nothing stands out

Do you guys have any idea? I'm starting to get crazy. I have a hunch that I'm not setting my connection correctly, but I can't see where.

Comment: Did you try a simple `openssl s_client`?  That would give you more debugging and parameters change possibilities than just `curl`. Did you try also without using NGINX?

Comment: Based on http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/asn1-encoding-routines-error-td45160.html the error seems related to **extensions** in the certificate, namely there "S/MIME Capabilities" OID (1.2.840.113549.1.9.15). So did you try with another certificate? What does it look like? How did you generate it?

Comment: "http://unrestful.io/2015/10/09/alpn-java.html" => ALPN only in Java 9, not 8. OR some modified classes for Java 8 here: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/alpn-chapter.html    I doubt that ALPN is the problem however.

Comment: Does your keystore entry have more than one cert i.e. a chain? If so how did you 'dump to ... files' for curl? If you put multiple certs in one file and use it for `curl --cert file` that does not produce the same behavior as Java, and thus is not a valid test. Can you post the cert(s) or at least `openssl x509 -text` of it(each one)? In Wireshark of the problem, does expanding each cert in the client Certificate message work correctly? PS: although some are kinky, most people on the internet don't like being whipped, so scourging is not a good strategy for seeking help :)

Comment: Patrick was on the good lead: I indeed use the subjectAltName to store the UUID of the client in the certificate. It seems that removing this UUID makes the test pass. For some reason, exporting to PEM or curl will remove this field, but using the certificate within java will fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that didn't read the comments: I figured it out: I was using the subjectAltName as a storage for something that isn't an alternative name.

It seems that Java is not happy with this and refuses the connection.